# The Mad God's Bargain: Missing reward?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Playing The Elder Scrolls Online: Tamriel Unlimited on Xbox One, I am at the end of the final portion of the Mage's Guild quest line.

> I decided that I wanted the 2 skill points more than saving Valaste, so I chose to send her away and get the Folium.  Upon receiving the Folium, the load screen appeared, which I believe it was to take me to current day Eyevea.  During the load screen the "Long load time" message appeared and the game crashed and took me back to the main screen.  I didn't receive 2 skill points, but I did get the ability to remember all books/scrolls/etc. from Shalidor once I reloaded the game.  Did I just get screwed out of 2 skill points or is there anything I can do?

Hopefully they will show once I play next, but I doubt they will.

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! +1 for the use of spoiler tags. Rest assured, you do not need to warn anybody of spoilers inside these marks, as they will only appear if a user deliberately hovers over them. Ive made another edit, but you can read more in my edit description.

Comment: You should have the quest reward item in your inventory, which will grant you skill points on activation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked your inventory? As far as I remember, the **Folium Discognitum** should be an item in your inventory (bound to your character).

You should be able to *activate/use* the item to actually get your two skill points. They won't magically appear just by completing the quest.

Comment: I played a little bit earlier and actually found this, so this is exactly what was wrong.  At the time it was hard to tell because the game crashed, so normally the skill points are issued in the dialogue at the end of the mission.

Answer (score 2):

There is generally only one thing you can do in circumstances like this, and that is to [contact the support team](https://help.elderscrollsonline.com/app/xboxaccountfaq). Follow the link, and if nothing on there helps, look to the right for "Get Help" and click "email" to start correspondence with the support team.

Massive Multiplayer Online Role Playing Games are complicated enough, from the developer point of view, let alone one based off The Elder Scrolls (which is already so expansive that a single player Elder Scrolls game often exhibits bugs to the extent found in an MMO).

For this reason, when bugs occur, the best thing you can do is report them. The developers do not want you getting screwed as much as you do. They want you to enjoy their game so you will buy stuff from them. So they will do their very best to ensure you receive your earned reward, and to make sure the bug is fixed, so that other players will not have the same problem.